# Make Pending Intent usable in any class

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

I need to be able to use a Pending Intent that I created in a Java class in any of my Classes how can I go about doing this?

```
PendingIntent notifIntent;
notifIntent = notification.contentIntent;
```

The reason for needing to use this is because I set the Pending Intent to whatever the Notifications Pending Intent is and then in a onClick event in my main activity I need to be reference this value.

Comment: You need to explain your usecase better: do you need to be able to update the global PendingIntent, or do you simply want to have access to a single never-to-change PendingIntent from everywhere in your app?

Comment: @jvmk I just want to be able to access it I don't want to change it

Comment: Ok, and how is it instantiated? Can it be instantiated statically?

Answer (score 0):

Alright an answer for this though might be by making a class just for this.  Something you can access anywhere in your code.

```
public class PendingIntentHolder {
    public static PendingIntent instance = new PendingIntent();
    static PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public static void setPending(PendingIntent intent) {
        pendingIntent= intent;
    }

    public static PendingIntent getPending() {
        return pendingIntent;
    }
}
```